Sources of non-congruence representations of the modular group
I'd be interested in any references that provide a source of non-congruence representations of the modular group or that discuss such representations. In my own field, vertex algebras, they have provided such representations and I'm curious if number theorists have encountered sources elsewhere.
As I am not a number theorist, I am not aware of what has been studied about non-congruence representations. Understandably a lot of what I've been able to find has been on congruence representations. I am aware of results determining congruence through unbounded denominator theorems though.
(Just for non-specialists, non-congruence here means that the kernel of the representation does not contain $\Gamma(N)$.)

You have to impose some conditions in order to have a chance to classify such representations.

@MoisheKohan I'm not seeking a rigorous classification, just any papers that discuss such representations? All I know is the VOA literature.

To me "non-rigorous math" is an oxymoron. Already the moduli space of $SU(2)$ representations of the modular group is 1-dimensional. Even topology of the moduli space of $SU(n)$-representations is hard to describe.

@MoisheKohan Are there any papers you know of that discuss non-congruence representations? I just want some entry into the literature, I'm not expecting specific results. I'm very happy to read a paper that tells me how hard non-congruence representations are to classify, that'd be delightful.

I will add a reference later on. It deals with representations of more general Fuchsian groups but applies to the modular group as well.

@MoisheKohan thank you, that would be appreciated.

@MoisheKohan or if you just let me know the author I can find it.

In order to convert my comments to an answer:
The group $\Gamma=PSL(2,\mathbb Z)$ is isomorphic to the free product $\mathbb Z_2\star \mathbb Z_3$. Therefore, one constructs representations $\Gamma\to G$ to a Lie group $G$ simply by choosing elements of orders 2 and 3 in $G$ and sending the generators of $\Gamma$ to these elements. It follows that the moduli space of representations (roughly speaking, the space of conjugacy classes) has dimension $\ge 1$ whenever $G$ is connected nonabelian semisimple. For instance in the case $G=SO(3)$ the moduli space of representations is 1-dimensional: The parameter is the angular distance (in $S^2$) between the fixed points of images of generators. You can find much more information on local structure of  spaces of representations of Fuchsian groups in
Weil, André, Remarks on the cohomology of groups, Ann. Math. (2) 80, 149-157 (1964). ZBL0192.12802.
Edit. If you take $G=GL(n,\mathbb C)$ and assume that $n$ is divisible by 6 then the moduli space has complex dimension
$$
\frac{n^2}{6} +1.
$$
One can make similar computations for general values of $n$.

Do you know of anything specialising to $G = \mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbb C)$?

For $n=2$ the moduli space will be complex 1-dimensional. I would need to do a computation for general $n$. @JPhy

Thanks for this, I'll have a proper read through.
